# iFrame from another website sometimes get " this page includes script from unauthenticated sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, iframe

On my rails3 app, I have an Iframe from a partner, but sometimes the ifrage on some browsers does not display the content and I get a warning on the url bar that says:

```
this page includes script from unauthenticated sources
```

Does anyone, know how can I use solve this issues.

[image]

Here is an example

Comment: Some details maybe? What browser, when this seems to happen? I guess it's not random.

Comment: Chrome and firefox, but I never try with IE and this is a random issues

Comment: Jean, if you want someone to help you you must be specific. If you google this error message all results are about making assets being served over SSL, but again you provided NO details so how is anyone supposed to guess if it's a case for you.

Comment: Further confirmation would be this meta question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208156/page-includes-script-from-unauthenticated-sources

Comment: Michael, I don't have any ads on the app

Comment: I'm no saying you have ads. What I'm saying is that you are loading some assets via http, that's why Chrome displays error. It such a basic problem that you should be able to find which asset is causing problem and fix it.